# What did I do wrong? C++ Newbie here

Tags: c++

I thought the output would be 70? (20+20+20+10=70) Why is it so large?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c=20;
    int d=10;
    int sum = a+b+c+d;
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dont post code as an image. (P.S: the value of a and b is unitialized, any result you get is random)

Comment: We can't know??

Comment: You did not give `a` and `b` a value. Please post the code into the question not just an image.

Comment: I'll give you a hint `int a,b,c =20` does not initialize all three with value 20. And please go through this once https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are not initializing the variables a and b. That means when you attempt to run your program, the computer is looking in memory for a value to use for each, and that number could be very big or very small. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a = 20,b = 20,c=20; //here, a and b are defined
   int d=10;
   int sum = a+b+c+d;
   cout << sum;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***C*** is the only one variable that you initialize to 20, the other 2 variables 
(***a*** and ***b***) are holding garbage..

so your math calculation is undefined behaviour.